# The procedure entry point GOMP_parallel could not be located in the dll

Tags: c++, qt, dll, openmp, libgomp

I have a QT application that uses OpenMP. (mingw, win8)
I want to use the .exe file without qt creator. I have already put all dlls in the build directory, but I still get this message when I run .exe file.

By the way everything works fine if I run it from Qt creator.

That's the only OpenMP code I have in my app:

```
#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic, 1)
```

And that's how I enable OpenMP in .pro file

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+= -fopenmp
QMAKE_LFLAGS +=  -fopenmp
```

Not sure if it matters but this code works in QThread. I mean I have one thread for GUI and the second one for computations.

Any ideas why this happens?

**upd**

And yes, I put `libgomp-1.dll` there too.

**upd 2**

Dependency walker just showed several missing microsoft dlls. Don't think that's the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the problem is solved.

I copied dlls from:

`\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\mingw492_32\bin\`

instead of:

`\Qt\Qt5.5.1\Tools\mingw492_32\bin\`

Maybe somebody will find it helpful.

And yeah, Dependency walker wouldn't help in the situation like this. That OpenMP dll wasn't missing it was just not the one I needed.